# Should I use a custom object for my events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

So I decided to implement an event to my project for the first time, and what came naturally to me was to first declare a delegate, then the event and use delegate as the event type.

```
class Counter
{
    public delegate void LimitReached();
    public event LimitReached OnLimitReached;

    int _myNumber = 0;
    public void Add(int i)
    {
        _myNumber += i;
        if (_myNumber > 10)
        {
            OnLimitReached?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my program class I would have the logic which adds a number

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        counter.OnLimitReached += Counter_OnLimitReached;
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding 1");
            counter.Add(1);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private static void Counter_OnLimitReached()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Counter limit reached!");
    }
}
```

And my question is.. Why not just use a void delegate rather than the `EventHandler` version where you need to actually pass in the sender and EventArgs if you don't have any information to pass in?

**Example 2**

```
class Counter
{
    public event EventHandler OnLimitReached;

    int _myNumber = 0;
    public void Add(int i)
    {
        _myNumber += i;
        if (_myNumber > 10)
        {
            OnLimitReached?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        counter.OnLimitReached += Counter_OnLimitReached;
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding 1");
            counter.Add(1);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private static void Counter_OnLimitReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Counter limit reached!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `System.Action` delegate, which is exactly the same as `LimitReached`. It's purely preference what you want to pass in to the delegate

Comment: I have made the experience that sometimes the `object sender, EventArgs e` convention becomes quite handy, especially when your project grows and/or you want to provide more data. E.g. getting the name of the counter, getting the current value, ...

Comment: Could you say that, you use a delegate which fits the project? For instance, if there is a need for me to pass data back from the publisher, then use an `EventHandler` or a custom delegate which has a couple of parameters, otherwise just use an Action or instance?